# Is it possible to read the data that is being written to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I have a simple java program hat writes to hdfs continuously. My understanding is that once a particular a particular block is written in HDFS, it can be accessed by other clients but in my case I have not been able to do so. I am writing a file of size 39 Kb and each write starting after 100 ms. I check the status of the file in hue but it shows 0 Bytes till the writing operation is going on and after the writing is complete it shows the complete file.I want to be able to read the data written in the file in at least say 4 Kb blocks. I am using the default configurations. 
Is my assumption correct? If so, what I am doing wrong? 
I using a VM with CDH 4.4.

Answer (score 3):

Coherency Model in Hadoop Definative guide says "After creating a file, it is visible in the filesystem namespace, as expected: However, any content written to the file is not guaranteed to be visible, even if the stream is flushed. So the file appears to have a length of zero: Once more than a block’s worth of data has been written, the first block will be visible to new readers."

```
hsync() or hflush() method of FSDataOutputStream should guarentee data is visible.
```